# Select all that apply type data extraction with Document Ai

Tags: cloud-document-ai

I need to use google cloud's [Document AI](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai?hl=en)
to convert pdf data into a csv format. However most of the data comes in the form of select-all-that-apply questions.

[This is an example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BGCBI.png)

From what I have read, the [Google Cloud Form Parser](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/form-parser)
Only extracts data as Key Value pairs, so it extracts checkboxes as a key value pair individually. As shown below.

[Each checkbox is its own key value pair, with the key being the name and the value being checked in or blank](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SOtVu.png)

I am not sure how I would go about extracting data as select all that apply questions. Even when looking at [custom processers](https://cloud.google.com/document-ai/docs/workbench/build-custom-processor) it seems like google cloud's document AI only takes key value pairs or text.

I was expecting that the form parser would already detect select that apply questions.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.